# Laravel query builder with where subqueries

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Good afternoon! I have a task to get all records of users whose number of inputs is greater than the number of outputs. I wrote the PostgreSQL code that should perform the given operation.

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users LEFT JOIN passages ON passages.user_id = users.id
WHERE (
        SELECT count(*) FROM passages
        WHERE passages.direction = 'in'
        AND passages.user_id = users.id
    ) > (
        SELECT count(*) FROM passages
        WHERE passages.direction = 'out'
        AND passages.user_id = users.id
    )
GROUP BY users.id;
```

I tried this, it works, but not as pretty as I want.

```
$whereSQL = "(SELECT count(*) > (
                        SELECT count(*) FROM passages WHERE passages.direction = 'out' AND passages.user_id = users.id
                     ) FROM passages
                       WHERE passages.direction = 'in' AND passages.user_id = users.id)";

        $users = User::query()->select('users.*')
            ->leftJoin('passages', 'passages.user_id', 'users.id')
            ->whereRaw($whereSQL)
            ->groupBy('users.id')
            ->get();
```

But in my heart, I don't know how to implement the same functionality in Laravel Eloquent. Please help!

Comment: welcome to so, what have you tried so far on eloquent

Comment: @bhucho https://prnt.sc/kf1qC-x9HGxf

Comment: add the code within this question by using the edit button

Comment: @bhucho Good, Ready!